# Формирование массива для полей с одинаковым названием

Tags: php, html

Есть ли какой-либо стандартный способ передать массив из формы на сервер:

```
<form>
<input name="nickname"> 
<input name="password">
<input name="nickname"> //генерируются скриптом
<input name="password">
</form>
```

Суть в том что имена инпутов одинаковые и в массиве $_GET они перезаписываются. Можно ли создать массив так что бы все эти инпуты автоматически заносили данные в один массив с названием `nickname` и `password`?

Comment: Смотря как инпуты расположены. Можно как минимум каждый nickname и password оборачивать в span при выводе  (они наверняка циклом выводятся)...... а потом просто через JS пробегаться по каждому блоку, занося всё  в массив и уже через ajax этот массив передать

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский можно и не через ajax, а через эту же форму. Суть вопроса в том что бы упростить это если это реально. У форм есть какая-то встроенная настройка создания массивов, но я не до конца понял как их сделать и можно ли подстроить их сюда.

Comment: В теории если поставить всем инпутам с именами name=nickname[], а паролям name=password[]  то будут приходит как раз массивы с данными, останется только сопоставить каждое имя с его паролем

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, то что нужно! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<input name="nickname[]" value=nickanme1>
<input name="password[]" value=password1>
<input name="nickname[]" value=nickanme2>
<input name="password[]" value=password2>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<pre><?print_r($_GET);?></pre>
```

Имееем в $_GET

```
Array
(
    [nickname] => Array
        (
            [0] => nickanme1
            [1] => nickanme2
        )

    [password] => Array
        (
            [0] => password1
            [1] => password2
        )
```

)